# Send Javascript variable to PHP to be saved to DB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi I am new to PHP and javascript, am unable to send a variable from Javascript to PHP page.
My Javascript code is separate .js file where I have declared a variable count which incremented at each correct answer that user gives. I wanted to pass this data to PHP page so that I can save it to database.

I have tried ajax post method and session storage but nothing seems to be working.

Is the below function correct for post data from JS to PHP?

```
function score(){
$.post("score_db.php",
{
  score:count

},
function(data){
  //
});
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `$_POST['score']` to receive the sent value?

Comment: Similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461786/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-via-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Using AJAX

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'score_db.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {score:count},
        success: function (data) {


        }
```

Refer

[Pass Javascript variable to PHP via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461786/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-via-ajax?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.  Here you can send data to php file {  score:count }.

```
   function score(){
    $.post( "score_db.php", {  score:count })
    .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Success" + data );
     });

   }
```

Docs Link for more information

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

send data from jquery like this...

```
    function score(){
    $.post( "score_db.php", {  score:count })
    .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Success" + data );
     });
    }
```

**in php file**

```
  if(isset($_POST['score']))
    echo $_POST['score']; //it will print jquery count variable
  else
    echo "nothing";
```