# how to pass parameter to php from html file using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have protfolio.html file and i have a table #gallery with categories in it. I want to update content of the #gallery, depending on chosen category using ajax. To achieve this I have php file which scans specific folder with the images relevant to category and returns html, however I don't know how to pass the location string to php script.
So far, i have this:

**index.html file:**

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getImages("/images/portfolio/gallery/*/")"><h5>view all</h5></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getImages("/images/portfolio/gallery/webdesign/")"><h5>webdesign</h5></a></li>
```

**Script**

```
function getImages(location)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'loadImages.php',
        data: location, 
        success: function(data) {
            $('#gallery').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

php file:

```
# To prevent browser error output

# Path to image folder
$imageFolder = $_POST["location"];

# Show only these file types from the image folder
$imageTypes = '{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.jpeg,*.JPEG,*.png,*.PNG,*.gif,*.GIF}';

# Set to true if you prefer sorting images by name
# If set to false, images will be sorted by date
$sortByImageName = false;

# Set to false if you want the oldest images to appear first
# This is only used if images are sorted by date (see above)
$newestImagesFirst = true;

# The rest of the code is technical
# Add images to array
$images = glob($imageFolder . $imageTypes, GLOB_BRACE);

# Sort images
if ($sortByImageName) 
{
    $sortedImages = $images;
    natsort($sortedImages);
} 
else 
{
    # Sort the images based on its 'last modified' time stamp
    $sortedImages = array();

    $count = count($images);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
    {
        $sortedImages[date('YmdHis', filemtime($images[$i])) . $i] = $images[$i];
    }

    # Sort images in array
    if ($newestImagesFirst) 
    {
        krsort($sortedImages);
    } 
    else 
    {
        ksort($sortedImages);
    }
}

$count = count($images);

for($i=1;$i<=$count; $i++)
{
    $
}

# Generate the HTML output
writeHtml('<ul class="ins-imgs">');

$count=1;

foreach ($sortedImages as $image) {

    # Get the name of the image, stripped from image folder path and file type extension

    # Get the 'last modified' time stamp, make it human readable

    # Begin adding
    if ($count==1 || $count%3==0)
    {
        writeHtml('<tr>');
    }

    writeHtml('<td>');
    writeHtml('<a  href="' . $image .'" data-lightbox="all" ><img src="' . $image .'" alt=""/></a>');
    writeHtml('</td>');

    if ($count==1 || $count%3==0)
    {
        writeHtml('</tr>');
    }

    $count++;
}

function writeHtml($html) 
{
    echo "document.write('" . $html . "');\n";
}
```

Comment: How does your PHP expect your data to be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass Javascript variable to PHP via ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461786/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-via-ajax)

Comment: So if your PHP file expects POST data, why are you using GET?

Comment: I don't know, thought it might work cause GET wasn't working too

Comment: Well I agree with @amura.cxg . The link he posted should give you the answer.

Comment: Maybe i'm passing the location wrong way? Every tutorial uses form, however I try to pass a href= argument..

Answer (score 0):

You need to send `key/value` pairs, not just `value` as you are doing:

Try:

```
$.ajax({
    .....
         data: {location : location},
    .....

});
```

then in php receive with `$_POST['location']`.

In browser console network tab, inspect the actual request and you will see exactly what is sent. This should always be your first point of troubleshooting ajax... inspecting the full request

Comment: `type` is "get".so he will recieve it as $_GET['location']

Comment: @OmarElawady .. right, conflict between what was originally attempted as post and type being now set to get

Comment: Maybe i'm passing the location wrong way? Every tutorial uses form, however I try to pass a href= argument..

Comment: @TomaszSklepowicz also you can't use `document.write` after a page loads. it will wipe out everything in the whole page. You need to return the full html as response ....inspect the request in your browser console!!

Comment: when i click the link <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getImages("/images/portfolio/gallery/*/")"><h5>view all</h5></a></li> i get unexpected token } error in this line. Is there a way to pass location differently?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getImages(location)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'loadImages.php',
        data: location, 
        success: function(data) {
            $('#gallery').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to pass location:

```
function getImages(location)
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'loadImages.php?location='+location, // simply add as query string
    success: function(data) {
        $('#gallery').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Then in your PHP file:

```
# Path to image folder
$imageFolder = $_GET["location"];
```

Comment: when i click the link <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getImages("/images/portfolio/gallery/*/")"><h5>view all</h5></a></li> i get unexpected token } error in this line. Is there a way to pass location differently? –