# Variable sent with AJAX is undefined in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a variable from Javascript to PHP using AJAX.

The HTML (index.html):

```
  <div class="table-popup">
    <ul>
      <li id="edit-toggle">Bearbeiten</li>
      <li>Zu Favoriten hinzufügen</li>
      <li>Datei öffnen</li>
      <li>Im Ordner öffnen</li>
      <li>Löschen</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="main-content">
    <h2 class="main-content-header">Datenbank</h2>
    <div id="table">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr class="table-row" tabindex="1">
            <th class="fixed-header"></th>
            <th>Dateiname</th>
            <th>Benutzer</th>
            <th>Erstelldatum</th>
            <th>Änderungsdatum</th>
            <th>Erste Zeile</th>
            <th>Kategorie</th>
            <th>Projekt</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        include_once('connect.php');
        $result = $connect->query("SELECT file.name AS 'filename', file.description AS 'filedescription', category.name AS 'categoryname', project.name AS 'projectname', user.name AS 'username', idFile
          FROM file, category, project, file_has_project, file_has_category, user, user_has_project, user_has_category
          WHERE file.idFile = file_has_project.file_idFile AND file_has_project.project_idProject = project.idProject AND file.idFile = file_has_category.file_idFile AND file_has_category.category_idCategory = category.idCategory AND user.idUser = user_has_project.user_idUser AND user_has_project.project_idProject = project.idProject AND user.idUser = user_has_category.user_idUser AND user_has_category.category_idCategory = category.idCategory AND user.idUser = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'");
          //echo "<tbody><td>".$result->num_rows."</td></tbody>";
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          echo "<tbody>";
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr class='table-row' tabindex='1' id='".$row['idFile']."'>";
            echo "<th class='table-edit-button fixed-header'><img src='images/open.gif' /></th>";
            echo "<td>".$row['filename']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
            echo "<td>-</td>";
            echo "<td>-</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['filedescription']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['categoryname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['projectname']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
          }
          echo "</tbody>";
        }
        ?>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The Javascript which is sending the AJAX request with jQuery (functions.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fileID;
  $('.table-edit-button').click(function() {
    fileID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  });
  $('#edit-toggle').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'edit.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { fileID : fileID },
      success: function(data) {
        alert("Success");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The PHP file (edit.php):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['fileID']))
 $fileID = $_POST['fileID'];
?>

<div class="edit-content">
  <h2 class="edit-content-header">Bearbeiten<img src="images/cross.gif" /></h2>
  <div>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <?php echo $fileID; ?>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Dateiname"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Benutzer"/>
      <textarea placeholder="Erste Zeile" rows="7em" cols="100"></textarea>
      <select name="Kategorie">
        <option disabled selected>Kategorie</option>
        <?php
          include_once('connect.php');
          $result = $connect->query("SELECT name FROM category");
          if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<option value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
            }
          }
        ?>
      </select>
      <select name="Projekt">
        <option disabled selected>Projekt</option>
        <?php
          $result = $connect->query("SELECT name FROM project");
          if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<option value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
            }
          }
        ?>
      </select>

      <img id="savebtn" src="images/save.gif" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The HTML displays data from a database in a table and each row has a button next to it. With jQuery I get the id of the row where the button has been clicked. I want to send this id to my php file to do some stuff there (irrelevant for now).
The problem I'm having is that I can't access the send variable (`fileID`) in my `edit.php` file.

The `alert` in the success part of the AJAX call gets executed.
What do I need to fix? I thought I had everything right.

I also tried to change the url of the AJAX call to `../edit.php` but that didn't work either. Then the success part wouldn't be executed.

And different variable names didn't work either.

The project structure is as follows:

- project (*)

  - edit.php
  - index.php
  - scripts (*)

    - functions.js

(*) directories

Edit:

> The error message: Notice: Undefined variable: fileID in C:\xampp\htdocs\kuhlnotesweb\edit.php on line 10

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: The console doesn't give any errors.

Comment: your data object is wrapped in brackets, it shouldn't be

Comment: Without them it's still not working (it now only has curly braces)

Comment: Just updated my answer, try using that code and the error should go away

Comment: Place `print_r($_POST);` at the top of the file to see if anything is getting set in the POST array.

Comment: Are you sure `$row['idFile']` is set?

Comment: Are you sure that `fileID` is set? You have to set that by clicking one button, then you click another for the AJAX call. Maybe the logic is a bit mixed up here?

Comment: Yes `fileID` is set I'm sure of this. Tested it with alert. The first click is to bring up a popupmenu the second is selecting something from that menu.

Comment: The problem is on the initial page load $fileID won't be set.  You need to wrap it with an if (isset()) like in my answer below

Comment: @Jay Blanchard: when I `console.log(data)` in the success part I see the value in the `$_POST` variable but not when it's displayed in the browser: http://i.imgur.com/QrqULvU.png

Comment: @MarshallOfSound: But that's what I'm doing ... (at the beginning of edit.php)

Comment: @Tywele check my updated answer, the error is how are you passing data

Comment: You may be looking for the result in the wrong place. Are you loading the edit.php and expecting to see the variable populated? If so, that will not work. AJAX is sending data to and expecting to receive data from edit.php. You will see the populated variable in that receipt, not by navigating to the page.

Comment: @mdamia: I already updated it like that in my question and also in my code and that wasn't the error.

Comment: @Tywele, but you aren't.. You check if the post is there and if it is you set $fileID.  If it isn't there you don't set it.  But later on you try and echo $fileID whether it has been set or not and that is your problem

Comment: @MarshallOfSound: Even if I do an isset check there it won't solve my problem.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard: Thanks I think that is my problem. But how can I do what I'm trying to achieve then? Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461786/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-via-ajax

Comment: Look at my comment and @MarshallOfSound's answer. Your error is at Line 10 when you echo out the variable while visiting the page directly. If you have to check to see if the variable `isset()` there OR change your `isset()` so that `$fileID = ''` if `$_POST['fileID'] *is not set*.

Comment: No one is listening to us @JayBlanchard :(

Comment: I think I am being misunderstood. I want to do the same thing as in the link I posted in my previous comment. I want to send a javascript variable via AJAX to my edit.php and use it there. How do I do that?

Comment: So I can do everything with `$_POST['fileID']` except using it in `echo`?

Comment: Or can I not use it in `edit.php` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution now:

functions.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fileID, fileName, fileDescription, fileCategory, fileProject;
  $('.table-edit-button').click(function() {
    fileID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  });

  $('#edit-toggle').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax-edit.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { fileID : fileID },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        fileName = data.filename;
        fileDescription = data.filedescription;
        fileCategory = data.categoryname;
        fileProject = data.projectname;
        $('#edit-fileid').val(fileID);
        $('#edit-filename').val(fileName);
        $('#edit-description').val(fileDescription);
        $('#edit-projectname').val(fileProject);
        $('#edit-categoryname').val(fileCategory);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

ajax-edit.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['fileID'])) $fileID = $_POST['fileID'];

include_once('connect.php');
$result = $connect->query("SELECT file.name AS 'filename', file.description AS 'filedescription', project.name AS 'projectname', category.name AS 'categoryname'
  FROM file, project, category, file_has_project, file_has_category
  WHERE file.idFile = file_has_project.file_idFile AND file_has_project.project_idProject = project.idProject AND file.idFile = file_has_category.file_idFile AND file_has_category.category_idCategory = category.idCategory AND file.idFile = '".$fileID."'");
$result = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo json_encode($result);
 ?>
```

edit.php:

```
<div class="edit-content">
  <h2 class="edit-content-header">Bearbeiten<img src="images/cross.gif" /></h2>
  <div>
    <form action="edit.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" id="edit-fileid" name="edit-fileid"/>
      <input type="text" id="edit-filename" name="edit-filename" placeholder="Dateiname"/>
      <input type="text" id="edit-username" name="edit-username" placeholder="Benutzer"/>
      <textarea id="edit-description" name="edit-description" placeholder="Erste Zeile" rows="7em" cols="100"></textarea>
      <select id="edit-categoryname" name="edit-categoryname">
        <option disabled selected value="category-first">Kategorie</option>
        <?php
          include_once('connect.php');
          $result = $connect->query("SELECT category.name FROM category,user,user_has_category WHERE user.idUser = user_has_category.user_idUser AND user_has_category.category_idCategory = category.idCategory AND user.idUser = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'");
          if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<option value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
            }
          }
        ?>
      </select>
      <select id="edit-projectname" name="edit-projectname">
        <option disabled selected value="project-first">Projekt</option>
        <?php
          $result = $connect->query("SELECT project.name FROM project,user,user_has_project WHERE user.idUser = user_has_project.user_idUser AND user_has_project.project_idProject = project.idProject AND user.idUser = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'");
          if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<option value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
            }
          }
        ?>
      </select>

      <input type="image" name="submit-button" id="savebtn" src="images/save.gif" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think there were many misunderstanding in what I was trying to achieve and how I was not able to understand how AJAX works exactly. `edit.php` is only a small part of HTML that gets included in `index.php` and the AJAX call I'm making gets made in the same file, so I was not able to use the variable I sent via AJAX in my edit.php file because at the point where I wanted to use it it wasn't even sent and thus the `$_POST['fileID']` was undefined.
My solution to this was that I created a seperate php file (`ajax-edit.php`) where I retrieve the information I need from the database and return it as a JSON object. With this I am able to use the information from the JSON object to change the value of the input fields.

Thank you for the help everybody and I am sorry that I was so stubborn ^^.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX returns the content of the page in the data success variable.  Trying console.log(data) and you should see you variable has been echoing into the returned HTML.

If not, check in the dev tools that the fileID parameter is actually attached to the request.

**UPDATE**

```
<div class="edit-content">
  <h2 class="edit-content-header">Bearbeiten<img src="images/cross.gif" /></h2>
  <div>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <?php
          if (isset($_POST['fileID'])) {
               echo $_POST['fileID'];
          }
      ?>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Dateiname"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Benutzer"/>
      <textarea placeholder="Erste Zeile" rows="7em" cols="100"></textarea>
      <select name="Kategorie">
        <option disabled selected>Kategorie</option>
        <?php
          include_once('connect.php');
          $result = $connect->query("SELECT name FROM category");
          if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<option value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
            }
          }
        ?>
      </select>
      <select name="Projekt">
        <option disabled selected>Projekt</option>
        <?php
          $result = $connect->query("SELECT name FROM project");
          if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<option value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
            }
          }
        ?>
      </select>

      <img id="savebtn" src="images/save.gif" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I did that and the variable did get echoed in the data variable. But I still get the error message on the website itself.

Comment: Your variable is showed in the returned HTML content ?

Comment: Yes it is. *not enough characters to post comment*

Comment: The error does not appear on my local files, are you sure you copied my code correctly.  The `if (isset())` should deal with the undefined problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a syntax error in your js when you try to pass data 
your code. see js fiddle example  http://jsfiddle.net/mdamia/njd8m0g5/4/. how to get the value from the tr.

```
  data: ({ fileID : fileID }),
```

should be data:

```
 { fileID : fileID } // no ()
```

Tested and it works.

from [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
  })
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: What happens if you try to access edit.php from the browser?

Comment: I don't quite understand. If I view edit.php through the browser it gets displayed(?) just like it should (with the error message because of the PHP variable being not defined.)

Comment: of course,you have $_POST['fileID'] in your edit.php you cannot access it without sending 'fileID' param

Comment: But didn't I do that in `functions.js`?

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Tested the code and it works. that s the only thing you have to change, I was able to echo data back from server to the browser and it works

Comment: @MarshallOfSound not the bracket but the parenthesis, they should not be there, updated post with example from jquery api

Comment: If you want to call them parenthesis thats ok but ({a: 1}) == {a: 1}.  The brackets don't effect the value

Comment: This was only a *part* of the problem, the other part being how `$fileID` is being set on Line 10 when accessing the page directly in the browser.

Comment: @MarshallOfSound we are not arguing the value of ({a: 1}) == {a: 1} here, the ajax syntax is wrong.