# How can I send parameters to php script (with ajax) so that they will be included on the server side?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following function:

```
function myFunction () {
    $.getJSON('remote.php', function(json) {
        var messages = json;

        function check() {
             ...
```

and I call there the remote.php script which makes a simple select query and returns all data with json.
I would like to pass a parameter to this query called `time`, which will be filled earlier in my code by:

```
var actualTime = new Date(params);
```

I know that on php script I have to do:

```
$time = $_POST['time'];
```

but how should I modify my jquery then to pass this argument further?

Comment: Use `$.ajax` or `$.post`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Javascript variable to PHP via ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461786/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-via-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass an object to [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).  It will be sent to PHP as `$_GET`.

```
$.getJSON('remote.php', {
    time: actualTime.toJSON()
}, function(json) {
    var messages = json;
});
```

Then your date will be in PHP as `$_GET['time']`.  I'd suggest converting to a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) object so you can [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) it as you need.

```
$time = new DateTime($_GET['time']);
```

If you want to use `$_POST` instead, then you'll have to change to using `$.post`.

```
$.post('remote.php', {
    time: actualTime.toJSON()
}, function(json) {
    var messages = json;
}, 'json');
```

Comment: thanks, why did you use actualTime.toJSON()? Can I just write: `time: actualTime` ?

Comment: @user3766930: `actualTime` is a `Date` object.  I used `toJSON()` to convert it to a string that PHP understands.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way of passing it with POST instead of GET? and is there any specific reason why you suggested GET instead of POST?

Comment: @user3766930: If you are using the `$.getJSON` function, then the parameters will be sent via `GET`.  If you need to use `POST`, you'll have to switch to `$.post` instead.