# js variables to PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, html, mysql

trying to send the javascript variables x and y from play.php in a PHP page xyz.php using AJAX but not being able to do so. could you guys be kind and tell me what's wrong here?

```
function clicked(evt){
            var e = evt.target;
            var dim = e.getBoundingClientRect();
            var x = evt.clientX - dim.left;
            var y = evt.clientY - dim.top;

            $( document ).ready(function() {

                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: 'play.php',
                   data: {X: x },
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                      alert("success! X:" + data);
                   }

                 });

              });
}
```

and in xyz.php

```
<?php 
   if (isset($_GET["X"])) {
     $x = $_GET["X"];
     echo $x;
   }else{
     echo 'no variable received';
   }
?>
```

Comment: you're doing a POST request and you're getting at your php file by GET method.

Comment: You are using POST method in your AJAX call, so you have to check $_POST in your php script instead of $_GET.

Comment: How is `clicked` being called?  Why is `$( document ).ready(function() {` *inside* that function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Javascript variable to PHP via ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461786/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-via-ajax)

Comment: How do you pretend `clicked` function be called? can you post your HTML code

Comment: this is my html code <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500">
                <g transform="translate(30 30)" onclick="clicked(evt)"><rect id="rect1" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="red"/></g>
            </svg>

Comment: i want that when i click that rectangle it should send the x & y coordinates as variables to xyz.php and from there i want them to be stored in my db.

Comment: @muzibaloutche see at my edit answer

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your data using "POST" and accepting using "GET"

Please rewrite PHP code like below

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["X"])) {
    $x = $_POST["X"];
    echo $x;
}else{
    echo 'no variable received';
}
?>
```

And check if it working

Comment: @muzibaloutche, alert the value of x in javascript. What it is showing?

Comment: still nothing. i can see this from console: play.php:49 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined for this line: $( document ).ready(function() {

Comment: you have to include jquery library before start your jquery code. You will get it from https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#hammerjs. as per the docs add <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script> in the head tag of your html page

Comment: did that as well. still nothing, Arun.

Answer (score 0):

according to your HTML you can bind on click as is shown below, [here the example working](https://jsfiddle.net/5hopk73e/1/)  you have 2 mistakes in your code the first, the event ready is fired when your window is loaded so this must be outside:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //svg selector you can adapt it what you need
   $('svg').on('click', function(evt){
     var e = evt.target;
     var dim = e.getBoundingClientRect();
     var x = evt.clientX - dim.left;
     var y = evt.clientY - dim.top;

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'play.php',
       data: {X: x },
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert("success! X:" + data);
       }

     });  
   });
});
```

And Second you're getting the parameters by GET, they should be gotten by POST.

```
if (isset($_POST["X"])) {
 $x = $_POST["X"];
 echo $x;
}else{
  echo 'no variable received';
}
```

Comment: with your method I am getting everything that is written on that particular page as a long n lengthy alert message(all my script of the page) which is bigger than the size of my screen with no close button. I had to force quit eclipse n then relaunch it to be able to work again.

Comment: set id to the element and get it with the selector: `<g id="square"  ...` and method like this `$('#square') ...` @muzibaloutche

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP Script should be :

```
<?php 
    if ( isset($_POST["X"]) ) {
        $x = $_POST["X"];
        echo $x;
   }else{
       echo 'no variable received';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a blend of a couple different solutions. I received error messages when binding the `<g>` svg element directly with the `onclick` event. So I took a little more indirect route. I added an `id` tag to the `<g>` element and then created the jQuery listener for a click event on that and then called the function. Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aedo6pmc/2/

Here's the `svg` element:

```
<svg xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink"; width="500" height="500"> <g transform="translate(30 30)" id="gSquare"><rect id="rect1" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="red"/></g> </svg>
```

And the javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#gSquare').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        clicked(e);
    });

    function clicked(evt){
        e = evt.target;
        dim = e.getBoundingClientRect();
        x = evt.clientX - dim.left;
        y = evt.clientY - dim.top;
        console.log(x + ' ' + y);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'play.php',
            data: {X: x },
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert("success! X:" + data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Just noticed Jose updated his answer to include the same type of approach. He binds it directly to the `svg` element which may be enough, but be sure that if your page has more than one `svg` on the page, that you want the same behavior for each `svg`.

Comment: I am still unable to echo x in my other php page plus with your solution, I can see the x and y in console but in the other html page, it's still "no variable received" being echoed, plus the alert window with "success X:" is still huge with all the script of the page in it.