# Edit database variables with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, database

I'm quite new to JavaScript so I hoped I could get some help with these questions.
I need to save a JavaScript variable (Just a simple number) to a database. I also need to be able to see the current value on 2 websites (using PHP to retrieve it on the second website).

My code now:

```
Voorraad: <input id="stock1" type=text" style="width:30px" value="10">

<input type="submit" value="Kopen" onclick="javascript:Kopen(event);">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function Kopen(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var stock1 = document.getElementById("stock1");
  var newNumber = parseInt(stock1.value) - 1;
  stock1.value = newNumber;
  if (stock1.value <= 0) {
      stock1.value = 0;

  }
```

I know I will need to use AJAX to do this, I have seen a question that is similar but it lacks a database connection and I am not sure how to use those pieces of code: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461786/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-via-ajax)

My questions are; How do I write a JavaScript variable to (mysql)database using ajax?

Comment: You should read about AJAX, it is really awesome, You can do more stuff with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer data from PHP to javascript by writing a javascript object into you script file:

```
<script>
var data_object = {
"id": <?php echo data->id ?>,
"role": <?php echo data->name ?>
}
</script>
```

This object is now available in the page via Javascript.

```
console.log(user_object.data)
```

In this way you can use your java script variable in server side  script.
Hope this will work out.

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose is of the seperate parts (id, role), and where to implement this?

Comment: I just wrote it as an example, you can take the reference only. Its not the exact answer.
And parts(id, role) are database fields that fetched using the query.