# Passing a JavaScript array to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a list like this in a php file:

```
<ul id="alist">
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
</ul>
```

Using jquery I've been able to grab that list:

```
var array = [];
$("#alist li").each(function() {
    array.push($(this).text())
});
```

After reading several posts about using json, ajax, this is what i have tried without success. In my js file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "checklist.php",
    data: { kvcArray : array},
    success: function() {
        alert("Success");
    }
});
```

In my PHP file:

```
<?php
  $myArray = $_POST['kvcArray'];
  var_dump($myArray)
?>
```

I get a result of "null", any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to echo the posted data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Comment: Echo is still returning Null

Comment: Is your `success` callback calling the `alert`?

Comment: Yes it says success

Comment: What if you do `success: function(data){alert(data);}` ?

Comment: It passes the entire php file

Comment: Including the `<?php`? If not, change `var_dump($myArray)` to `echo $myArray[0];` Then it should just display `Item1`

Comment: Look at your response to see what data you're transferring.$.ajax({
   success: function(response){console.log(response);});

Comment: @Xorifelse without the php, it returns in the alert box the html file. I also did that with alert(array) - this returns my array that i want inside my php

Comment: Well @Bryant I copied your code, and it works just fine.

Comment: @Xorifelse i will try a separate folder and see what could influence the outcome. thanks

Comment: I still get null! after isolating to a different folder and two files... wtf

Comment: It is working fine on my system too. It is not clear to me what issue are you facing, can you clarify it a bit? I am getting `array(3) {...}` in the network response for checklist.php.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A straight forward way to do it is appending the values of your array to a hidden input field in a form.

1. Use jquery to grab the list values and push to an array
2. Convert the array into a string, ready for form submission
3. Add a hidden input to a form with an id and an empty value attribute
4. Append your string to this input field.
5. On submit of your post, on PHP you will be able to see your array as a string.
6. Convert back into array on the php side and presto!

You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I misunderstood the question, but this works fine on my computer (it logs your array data):

--- index.php ---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Your list -->
    <ul id="alist">
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Your JS -->
    <script>
    var array = [];
    $("#alist li").each(function() {
        array.push($(this).text())
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checklist.php",
        data: { kvcArray : array},
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
    });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

--- checklist.php ---

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Comment: This returns to me "Array ( )" and if i try it with a var_dump it gives me array(0) { }. I'm really confused as to why its different for me than everyone else...

Answer (score -1):

I found a good example of passing values through the query string at http://webcheatsheet.com/php/passing_javascript_variables_php.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

width = screen.width;
height = screen.height;

if (width > 0 && height >0) {
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/main.php?width=" + width + "&height=" + height;
} else 
    exit();

</script>
```

php

```
<?php
echo "<h1>Screen Resolution:</h1>";
echo "Width  : ".$_GET['width']."<br>";
echo "Height : ".$_GET['height']."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Also this problem has several similar posts on stack overflow including this one for a Javascript post option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461786/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-via-ajax