# Passing Array from Javascript to PHP and insert it in MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i Have a code here that gets data from spreadsheet and display it in array.

```
var publicSpreadsheetUrl = "link";
var tabletop = Tabletop.init( {
                             key: publicSpreadsheetUrl,
                             callback: showInfo,
                             simpleSheet: true 
                        })
function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
    ArrMasterfile.push(data);
    console.log(ArrMasterfile);
}
```

this is the output

```
0:{Title: "", Data "", Title: "Data ", Title: "Data ", Title: "Data ", …}
1:{Title: "", Data "", Title: "Data ", Title: "Data ", Title: "Data ", …}
```

my question is how can I pass that array in PHP? My target here is to save that in mysql. TYSM

Comment: use AJAX or POST it via <form>

Comment: Use ajax call to pass params to PHP and in php file try json_decode(). You will get php array.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461786/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-via-ajax